# Standardised Precipitation-Evapotranspiration Index database export issues

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have tried to export it as GeoTIFF format as well as export as table. But the data of SPEI doesn't export at all. Why is this so? How can I export it? Here is the code given below.

```js
// Retrieve the last date from the SPEI dataset.
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("CSIC/SPEI/2_9").
  filterDate('2022-12-01', '2023-01-01');

// Select the 24-month analysis.
var spei24 = dataset.select('SPEI_24_month');

// Set the visualization ranges and color palette.
var visParams = {
  min: -2.33,
  max:  2.33,
  palette: [
    '8b1a1a', 'de2929', 'f3641d',
    'fdc404', '9afa94', '03f2fd',
    '12adf3', '1771de', '00008b',
  ]
};

// Set the map center to Spain's location.
Map.setCenter(-3.75, 40.47, 4);

// Display the SPEI 24-month layer.
Map.addLayer(spei24, visParams, 'SPEI 24 month');
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the export code that didn't work and explain what you mean by "doesn't export at all". Is there an error message?

Answer (score 0):

finally found a way to export as tiff file.....

here is the code where you just need to add area of interest.

```
// var aoi =


// Retrieve the last date from the SPEI dataset.
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("CSIC/SPEI/2_9").
  filterDate('2022-12-01', '2023-01-01');

// Select the 24-month analysis.
var spei24 = dataset.select('SPEI_24_month').mean().clip(aoi);

// Set the visualization ranges and color palette.
var visParams = {
  min: -2.33,
  max:  2.33,
  palette: [
    '8b1a1a', 'de2929', 'f3641d',
    'fdc404', '9afa94', '03f2fd',
    '12adf3', '1771de', '00008b',
  ]
};


// Display the SPEI 24-month layer.
Map.addLayer(spei24, visParams, 'SPEI 24 month');
Map.centerObject(aoi,8)

// Export the SPEI 24-month image to Google Drive.
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: spei24,
  description: 'SPEI_24_month_export',
  folder: 'SPEI', // Specify the folder in your Google Drive where you want to export the image.
  region: aoi.geometry(), // Set the region to the geometry of your AOI.
  scale: 30, // Set the scale (in meters) according to your preference.
  crs: 'EPSG:4326' // Set the CRS (Coordinate Reference System) according to your preference.
});
```